# Defining columns in an SQLite Database table

Tags: android

I copied an SQLite Database example, where I created a table with 3 fields/columns and inserted one record with 3 values, as follows:

```
>SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
>db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FunnyNames(Email VARCHAR(255), FirstName    VARCHAR(255), LastName VARCHAR(255));");
>db.execSQL("INSERT INTO FunnyNames VALUES('abath@aol.com','Anita','Bath')");
```

..and I received this error message

```
>12-28 11:35:00.896: E/SQLiteLog(8857): (1) table FunnyNames has 1 columns but 3 values were supplied
```

didn't I define the columns correctly?

Comment: did you try uninstalling the app and then run ur project again?

Answer (score 3):

`IF NOT EXISTS` only creates the table if it didn't exist. Likely you already have a table with that given name in the database file, and that table only has 1 column.

Uninstall your app or clear its data in the app manager to remove the old database file. Or add `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FunnyNames` before the `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: If the app is in production (although I guess this is not the case)  `onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)` should be used.

Comment: Yes, use `SQLiteOpenHelper` for versioning actual databases and don't work with `Context.openOrCreateDatabase()` directly.

Answer (score -1):

You've missed the primary key of the table. Every table needs an primary key (which is an unique id) for referencing data. Modify your create statement as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FunnyNames(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Email VARCHAR(255),   FirstName    VARCHAR(255), LastName VARCHAR(255));
```